# TextView only updated every x seconds

Tags: android, textview, countdowntimer

I have the following code which should change the textview every second but only does every 2 or even every 4 seconds:

```
final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

new CountDownTimer(remain, 1000)
{
        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            tv.setText("Done");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            tv.setText(timeCalculate(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }
}.start();

public String timeCalculate(long ttime)
{
    long days, hours, minutes, seconds;
    String daysT = "", hoursT = "", minutesT = "", secondsT = "";

    days = (Math.round(ttime) / 86400);
    hours = (Math.round(ttime) / 3600) - (days * 24);
    minutes = (Math.round(ttime) / 60) - (days * 1440) - (hours * 60);
    seconds = Math.round(ttime) % 60;

    if (days == 1)
        daysT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d day", days);
    if (days > 1 || days == 0)
        daysT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%d days", days);

    if (hours == 1)
        hoursT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ", %d hour", hours);
    if (hours > 1 || hours == 0)
        hoursT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ", %d hours", hours);

    if (minutes == 1)
        minutesT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ", %d minute", minutes);
    if (minutes > 1 || minutes == 0)
        minutesT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), ", %d minutes", minutes);

    if (seconds == 1)
        secondsT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), " %d second", seconds);
    if (seconds > 1 || seconds == 0)
        secondsT = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), " %d seconds", seconds);

    return daysT + hoursT + minutesT + secondsT + " remaining";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does timeCalculate do ?

Comment: Sorry added the code...

Comment: is u want a countdown timer ?

Comment: Yes and it works. Only the TextView is not updated fast enough.

Comment: did you log the string before putting it in the textview to make sure it is correct ?

Comment: Yes it is correct. It actually also shows the LogCat output every second with the correct output.

Comment: u solve the issue.I think the problem for the delay is u use lot of calculation in onTick method i am not sure about it.

Comment: Well but why does the LogCat output every second?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the TextView, make sure to call `postInvalidate()` on the TextView / containing view.

Also, I would add spaces between each + when joining the strings together in the new method you posted ;)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. postInvalidate() did not help :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this code mInitialTime remaining time in long

```
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mInitialTime, 1000) {
        StringBuilder time = new StringBuilder();

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // txt_RemainingTime.setText(DateUtils.formatElapsedTime(0));
            txt_remainingTime.setText("00:00:00");


        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            time.setLength(0);

            if (millisUntilFinished > DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS) {
                long count = millisUntilFinished / DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;
                if (count > 1)
                    time.append(count).append(" days ");
                else
                    time.append(count).append(" day ");

                millisUntilFinished %= DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS;

            }

            StringBuilder value = time.append(DateUtils
                    .formatElapsedTime(Math
                            .round(millisUntilFinished / 1000d)));

            String i = value.toString();
            int length = i.length();

            if (length < 6) {
                i = "00:" + i;
            }
            if (length == 7) {
                i = "0" + i;
            }
            txt_remainingTime.setText(i);
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: mInitialTime should be in millsecond

Answer (score 0):

Funny. If I take all the code from my method and put it inside the onTick method it works! Same Code, nothing changed except removing the extra method.
Don't know why though.